# installing ggplot2 into jupyter notebook

Tags: r, ggplot2, jupyter-notebook

I'm a uni student who doesn't really understand what I'm doing but when I enter install.packages("ggplot2") into my jupyter notebook, i get the error
Warning message:
"unable to access index for repository https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.6:
cannot open URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/PACKAGES'"Packages which are only available in source form, and may need
compilation of C/C++/Fortran: 'cli' 'farver' 'isoband' 'rlang'
'scales' 'tibble' 'vctrs'
These will not be installed
installing the source packages 'pillar', 'lifecycle', 'ggplot2'

Warning message in install.packages("ggplot2"):
"installation of package 'lifecycle' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("ggplot2"):
"installation of package 'pillar' had non-zero exit status"Warning message in install.packages("ggplot2"):
"installation of package 'ggplot2' had non-zero exit status"

When I tried to search out answers, I can't really figure it out.

The version of notebook I'm using is 6.5.4
The server is running on this version of Python:
Python 3.11.5 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Sep 11 2023, 13:26:23) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]

If anyone can help with (very!) easy to follow instructions that would be great.
I've tried installing tidyverse, install.packages("ggplot2", source="type") and I get the same error.

Thanks in advance!

If anyone can help with (very!) easy to follow instructions that would be great.
I've tried installing tidyverse, install.packages("ggplot2", source="type") and I get the same error.

Comment: The address that pops up there is not valid. `https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.6` gives an error. You need to set which cran URL to use and make sure it is a good one. (I'm not recalling how right now but digging in some docker / r-docker files may help you find a lead.) Alternatively, Anaconda/conda makes working with the R kernel in Jupyter  much easier. I would normally suggest that but it seems you want really old version of R and so switching to the Anaconda Distribution may not be advisable without maybe testing in online systems first? Everything I know is using R ver 4+

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/binder-examples/r-conda) is where I was suggesting you could fork wondering if you could test setting versions in the `environment.yml` to be corresponding to the old one you want. Right now that is set to use 3.6; however, I would test in the resulting sessions. I know from [my used of a variation here](https://github.com/fomightez/millefy-binder/blob/master/binder/environment.yml) that you get version 4+ of R i you just run with `r-base` with no version specified.

Comment: <continued> Actually if you use the resources available [there](https://github.com/binder-examples/r-conda) where it says 'Jupyter + R' you probably get what you are looking for in a temporary session already? You'll **need to click [here to launch a session with the proper entry](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/binder-examples/r-conda/HEAD)?**. (I've requested the fix it but it hasn't been fixed yet.) That session is temporary and will time out with inactivity and so make sure you download anything useful you make immediately.

Comment: <continued> You can drag and drop a notebook file from your local system to a later running session to work on it again. The file panel on the left side accepts drag and drops from your desktop into the browser window. Just make sure you are holding down the mouse as you drag into that pane.